# Javascript debugging doesn't work : Visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am unable to debug the inline JavaScript in CSHTML (view) in my MVC application. I have tried putting "debugger" command, setting up break point as usually do in the code file & moving the entire script to a JavaScript file. But, debugger points are never hit. It seems to that JavaScript debugging is disabled.

However, if I create a brand new MVC application, it work as expected.
Appreciate your help here.

Tools: Visual studio 2015, IE 11 and Windows 10 enterprise

Comment: We cant help you, you've just said you've got a problem without any way of us helping

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem